# DIV not showing up on load

Tags: javascript, slideshow

When you first visit the page, the Project-1 description does not load. As you scroll to the second image, it will ease out. I want the first project's description to load right away. I did not write the functions.js, and I can't find the code I need in it. I'm a hack, trying to learn by poking and prodding.

I have "found" all instances of "project-1" in the script, and removed them one at a time to see the effects. No luck.

I also want the Up Arrow to change transparency like the Down Arrow OnMouseOver, but it's disabled on all Project-1 images

Help? Thank you!

http://boellingsmith.com/design.html

Comment: I'm sad you will have to delve a little bit into the kind of code this page is using. For instance try to investigate if it is using any framework, and where are located the loading events.

Rgds.

Comment: Your URL is returning a 404 error for me. Also awaiting someone to link the "Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is not a do-something-for-me service." page or something like that. You're supposed to show us some code and show what you've tried before making a question.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo Fabrício. Fixed. I don't know what part of the code would be useful, if I knew that, I'd make the fix.

Comment: @user1397436: Remove `class="top"` from `<a id="up" class="top" href="#"></a>` for the Up Arrow OnMouseOver to work.

Comment: @neo108 Thank you! That worked! Now I'll go back and figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (add code below):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.project-1").addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I was expecting to remove code, rather than add more. Is this a work-around or the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can also remove the whole code above and just add class of `active` to the span with class `project-1`.